# User Confirmation

Tags: interaction-design, user-journey, interactive-ui

Let me give a example:

[image]

in this case is redundant ask for the user the confirmation?

Is better just put:
[image]

I think the second way I can say to for the user 'you can return for your activities, we will inform when the export is ready' is a good way to do this journey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First screen is correct. You’re asking a question that requires an answer via an interaction. This can be answered in natural language by user’s interaction. Moreover, a simple **Yes** would be a lot better.

The second screen isn’t right. The system is not asking anything, just providing an information. Having 2 buttons for this isn’t correct. If you want to use buttons, a simple “I understand” button should suffice.

However, what you mentioned in your last paragraph is a good idea, instead of having the user wait for the process to be finished, just do as you say, let the user do whatever she wants and get back to this process once she’s notified everything is ready

Comment: agreed. I'd put the status (spinner or progress bar) in line with the item that you just requested the export for. Possibly replacing the export button to avoid duplicate requests.

Comment: @Devin If i ask for the user, whats the  formatted he would like to export a file inside the body of the modal is okay do that? Is like Sketch ask for u 'wich artboard would you like to export?'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but just in case it's what I understand, I'd recommend to keep all elements of a flow together. for example, the format (I assume you mean extension or type here, is that correct?) should be added **before** user clicks the **Export** button. If this is what you mean and you need additional help, please create another question so it doesn't mix with this one since both questions are different :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need a confirmation for this action since there is no harm done if they export the file. I only use confirmation dialogs for things that can't be un-done.

In the instance you've illustrated, I'd suggest that you replace the "export" button with a status indicator (ideally a progress bar, but a spinner if that's easier) letting the user know that they successfully requested an export and to prevent duplicate requests.